# Celery: TypeError when invoking a celery task in a loop

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I am getting `TypeError` when invoking a celery task in a loop. The first task runs fine but subsequent tasks fail due to `TypeError (function takes 1 argument 3 given)`.

This is the function definition:

```
@celery.task 
def create_thumbnails(filename, thumbnail_width, send_mail_flag=False):
```

This is how i am invoking it:

```
for index, (image, image_name) in enumerate(images_list):
    create_thumbnails.delay(image_name,ITEM_THUMBNAIL_WIDTH)
```

This is the error I am getting in celery log:

```
[2015-10-04 14:04:44,222: ERROR/MainProcess] Task tasks.create_thumbnails[eff8c190-5876-4e9c-8a6f-83ad530d25ff] raised unexpected: TypeError('create_thumbnails() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
  R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
  return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: create_thumbnails() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

What could be the possible reason for this? BTW, I am using `RabbitMQ` for queuing up the tasks.